# How to define a Gnomonic projection WKT for the Moon

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, moon

I need to warp a global dataset into a set of 6 rasters to form a cubemap for rendering the Moon. These rasters must be in Gnomonic projection in order for the rectangular raster bounds to line up along longitude lines. I am not finding any resources online that help with defining a Gnomonic projection for celestial bodies besides Earth.

I was able to use gdalwarp (through the OSGeo4W shell) to generate Stereographic projection rasters that are close to what I am looking for through commands like the following:

```
> gdalwarp -te -45 -45 45 45 -te_srs moon_cyl.prj -ts 16384 16384 -t_srs moon_stereog_eq_long_0.prj Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.tif WarpedGlobalToEq0.tif
ERROR 1: Invalid dfSouthLatitudeDeg
ERROR 1: Invalid dfSouthLatitudeDeg
Creating output file that is 16384P x 16384L.
Processing Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -32768) for image Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.tif.
Copying nodata values from source Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.tif to destination WarpedGlobalToEq0.tif.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

With the projection `moon_stereog_eq_long_0.prj` defined by this WKT:

```
PROJCS["Moon_Stereographic_AUTO",
    GEOGCS["Moon 2000",
        DATUM["D_Moon_2000",
            SPHEROID["Moon_2000_IAU_IAG",1737400.0,0.0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Decimal_Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

and varying the `Central_Meridian` and `Latitude_Of_Origin` was all I needed to do to switch center locations.

[image: Stereographic warped rasters]

The results, though, are unsatisfactory because Stereographic projection does not have straight longitude lines (or other great circle lines).

When I try to use a modified WKT with what I think will give me a Gnomonic projection, I get errors like one of the following:

```
PROJ: proj_create: Error -9 (unknown elliptical parameter name)
Cannot invert geotransform
buildCS: missing UNIT
```

What is the right way to define a Gnomonic projection for the Moon?

---

Quick Reference:

- [gdalwarp documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html)
- [Moon data source](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014)
- [USGS: Map projections, A working manual](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395)
- [ArcGIS Docs: Stereographic](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/stereographic.htm)
- [ArcGIS Docs: Gnomonic](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/gnomonic.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a valid WKT for a Gnomonic projection centered at 0,0:

```
PROJCS["Moon_Gnomonic_Equatorial",
    GEOGCS["Moon 2000",
        DATUM["D_Moon_2000",
            SPHEROID["Moon_2000_IAU_IAG",1737400.0,0.0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Decimal_Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Gnomonic"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
    PARAMETER["Longitude_of_Center",0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

I thought the change of the `PARAMETER` nomenclature was the change that made this work, but I may have been having problems with the south pole warp I was trying to do apart from the definition of the projection, which convoluted the problem.

[image: possibly correct Gnomonic]

> In this instance, though, it appears the corners of the raster are offset from the correct 45,45 degrees. This offset goes away when sufficiently zoomed in. I have no idea why. [image: Zoomed in Gnomonic vs Stereographic]

EDIT: I previously was under the assumption that the vertex of a cube projected onto a sphere corresponded to the 45/45 Lat/Long point. It does not. The true point is still `45*n` longitude, but the latitude is `+- 35.264` (`asin(sqrt(3)/3)`).

---

Quick Reference:

- [gdalwarp documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html)
- [Moon data source](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014)
- [USGS: Map projections, A working manual](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395)
- [ArcGIS Docs: Stereographic](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/stereographic.htm)
- [ArcGIS Docs: Gnomonic](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/gnomonic.htm)